# Add hint text at the below of the input field

Tags: android, kotlin, textfield, hint

At the moment, I have the simplest one-page application with one data entry field. I looked at a lot of examples, but I could not find the answer to my question: how do I add hint text at the bottom of the input field?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextUserId"
        android:layout_width="347dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="User"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/user_id"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextDeviveId"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextSessionId"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextDeviveId"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by at bottom or input field? Can you please give some examples or UI of what you want to do?

Comment: @MehulKabaria I updated my question - added a photo: that is, I would like to be able to write the name of this field under the input field (red color is optional)

Comment: Will the hint text stay permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a  Textview and Constrain it below your Edittext

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextUserId"
    android:layout_width="347dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="User"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/user_id"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextDeviveId"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextSessionId"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextDeviveId"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="user"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextUserId"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextUserId" />
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then if you want to show/hide it base on user interaction you can do something
like this in your activity

```
editTextUserId.setOnFocusChangeListener((view, b) -> {
        if(b){hint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
        else {hint.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}

    });
```

Comment: Thank you, it is great solution for me

Comment: Isn't it too much code and unnecessary to do it this way? It can be done with less code as I shared and the style can be turned off if you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_customer_no"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            app:helperTextEnabled="true"
            app:helperText="User">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextUserId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Customer No"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I tried it myself, it works for me, if you want, I can remove the border

Comment: It gets the job done. But based on the question he had a specific requirement for this